# SimpleTest PHP Scriptable Web Browser does not work on input type email

Tags: php, forms, email, autofill, simpletest

I am trying to use the PHP Scriptable Web Browser from simplest.org to automatically fill-in a form on a website.

The email field in the form is set to:

```
<input id="mail1" type="email" name="mail1">
```

etc.

If I try to fill in this email-field with:

```
$browser->setField('mail1', 'test@mail.com');
```

Nothing happens !!! (the filed stays blank, no problems with other fields where the type="text").

Is there a workaround for this "new" email field so I can still use the PHP Scriptable Web Browser?

I really would like to auto-fill in a form and submit it using PHP.

Comment: Maybe you can check the version of your component to ensuring you get the latest, supporting this input type.

Comment: the tag-library for parsing html dont know <input type="email">

Comment: Is there anyway I can add that to the tag-library roeb ?! Or do you have another suggestion maybe ?!

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it by using CURL in PHP.
There are some very good and interesting video's about that on YouTube.

Thnx all!!

Answer (score 0):

You should edit tag.php and add the following line in class SimpleTagBuilder, function createInputTag:

```
            'email' => 'SimpleTextTag',
```

For example you can put it here:

```
            ...
            'text' => 'SimpleTextTag',
            'email' => 'SimpleTextTag',
            'hidden' => 'SimpleTextTag',
            ...
```

However, this tool is not updated any more. Maybe it's better to use another tool, for example Selenium:
https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver